# Customers can't login in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, cookies

Customers can't login in my magento 1.8.1 store.
The page refreshes when you fill in your e-mail and password and push sudmit.
What is the problem?
My store is: www.stropdassenexpert.nl

Many thanks!

Comment: try to check to log files for clues, probably there is a error that results in a redirect.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you theme is not compatible with the 1.8.1 code.
There is a new security measure in 1.8. (Almost) Each POST must contain the session form key. 
The login form is one of those cases.
Add this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

In the following files inside the `<form>` tag.

```
app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/customer/form/login.phtml
app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/customer/form/register.phtml
```

I'm almost sure that there are other files that need this. If something else doesn't work, compare your template with the one from `base/default` and see if the form key is missing inside the form.